# Python, Tkinter, Application packaging and distributing with custom packages

Tags: python, software-recommendation, software-development

I have built an application on Tkinter in Python 3 and I want to package that application with all the dependent packages.

I would want to build the .exe application of my python script that installs python 3, some of the packages/dependencies, and install my python script as a .exe. I have heard of py2exe, but is that suggested?

How shall I have this and which software is recommended for it?

I do not have experience in packing and distributing software.